# Subcriber block Actionlib in the same node

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
I was tried to combining node with subscribe and actionlib in the same node.

I want to get 5 data from callback subscribe and then run it to actionlib.
but my program stuck on the callback and never run to actionlib

I'm quite new to actionlib, so please anyone can help me?
I will appreciate every help that i can get
thank you
best regards

here is the code i use :

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/PointStamped.h"
#include <move_base_msgs/MoveBaseAction.h>
#include <actionlib/client/simple_action_client.h>

bool moveToGoal(double xGoal, double yGoal);
double x[5];
double y[5];
int u = 0;
int n = 0;
bool waypoint = false;
bool goalReached = false;

void chatterCallback(const geometry_msgs::PointStamped& msg)
{
  ROS_INFO("I heard: [%f, %f]", msg.point.x, msg.point.y);

  if (u < 3)
  {
    x[u] = msg.point.x;
    y[u] = msg.point.y;

    ROS_INFO("Position X[ and Y: [%f, %f]", x[u], y[u]);
    u += 1;
  }
  if (u >= 3)
  {
    waypoint = true;
    ROS_INFO("waypoint done");
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "map_waypoint");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("clicked_point", 1000, chatterCallback);

  while (waypoint == true)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
      goalReached = moveToGoal(x[i], y[i]);
      ROS_INFO("start moving");
      ros::spinOnce();
      if (goalReached)
      {
        ROS_INFO("Congratulations![%f, %f]", x[i], y[i]);
        ros::spinOnce();
        // sc.playWave(path_to_sounds+"ship_bell.wav");
        // ros::spinOnce();
      }
      else
      {
        ROS_INFO("Hard Luck!");
            // sc.playWave(path_to_sounds+"short_buzzer.wav");
          }
        }
      }
      ros::spin();
      return 0;
    }

bool moveToGoal(double xGoal, double yGoal)
{
  // define a client for to send goal requests to the move_base server through a SimpleActionClient
  actionlib::SimpleActionClient<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction> ac("move_base", true);

  // wait for the action server to come up
  while (!ac.waitForServer(ros::Duration(5.0)))
  {
    ROS_INFO("Waiting for the move_base action server to come up");
  }

  move_base_msgs::MoveBaseGoal goal;

  // set up the frame parameters
  goal.target_pose.header.frame_id = "map";
  goal.target_pose.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();

  /* moving towards the goal*/

  goal.target_pose.pose.position.x = xGoal;
  goal.target_pose.pose.position.y = yGoal;
  goal.target_pose.pose.position.z = 0.0;
  goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
  goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
  goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.z = 0.0;
  goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;

  ROS_INFO("Sending goal location ...");
  ac.sendGoal(goal);

  ac.waitForResult();

  if (ac.getState() == actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState::SUCCEEDED)
  {
    ROS_INFO("You have reached the destination");
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    ROS_INFO("The robot failed to reach the destination");
    return false;
  }
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365272/subcriber-block-actionlib-in-the-same-node/) by [frizh](https://answers.ros.org/users/54903/frizh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you don't do `spinOnce()` or `spin()`,
the callback will not work and the waypoint will remain false.

A simple solution is to use

```
while (waypoint == true)
```

indicates an area of expertise

```
while(waypoint == false)
{
    ros::spinOnece();
}
while (waypoint == true)
```

You can do this by

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2020-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [frizh](https://answers.ros.org/users/54903/frizh/) on 2020-11-12**:
hii thanky you for your answer
I have recently do what you suggest, but it still not working.
It always subcribing my subscriber and cannot go on to my actionlib

I have tried to use spin or spinOnce also but when use spinOnce, subscriber won't listen my /clickedpoint.
but when i use spin, it always listening my topic and cannot go on to actionlib

here is the code i modified

```
ros::init(argc, argv, "map_waypoint");
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("clicked_point",1000 ,chatterCallback);
if (donewaypoint == false){ 

    ROS_INFO("Waiting Waypoint!");
    ros::spin();
```

}

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2020-11-12**:
Do you have the following output when you click on it?

```
ROS_INFO("I heard: [%f, %f]", msg.point.x, msg.point.y);
```

If there is no output, you may need to change `clicked_point` to `clickedpoint` in the following code

```
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("clicked_point",1000 ,chatterCallback);
```

**Comment by [frizh](https://answers.ros.org/users/54903/frizh/) on 2020-11-12**:
hii
tahnks for your reply
yeah i got the rosinfo like that.
in the code, when we got 4 point, it should change bool waypoint to true and starting goalreached
but in my case, after i goit 4 point, it not start goalreached program and always looping back to subscriber

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2020-11-12**:
Once spin() is called, it doesn't come back.
Therefore, I think it's better to use the method I showed before, which uses spinOnce().
Alternatively, you can run spin() in another thread.

**Comment by [frizh](https://answers.ros.org/users/54903/frizh/) on 2020-11-12**:
Hii miura
thanks for the reply
I have also tried that, but when use spinOnce, it only appears like this (even i publish the topic.

```
[ INFO] [1605171006.582843595]: Waiting Waypoint!
```

any refrence to do the spin() in another thread?
thanks in advance

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2020-11-12**:
Let's try.

```
#include <pthread.h>
// ...
void *spin_thread(void *argv)
{
    ros::spin();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // ...
    pthread_t spin_tid;
    pthread_create(&spin_tid, NULL, spin_thread, NULL);
    while(waypoint == false)
    {
        ROS_INFO("Waiting Waypoint!");
    }
    while (waypoint == true)
    // ...
```

**Comment by [frizh](https://answers.ros.org/users/54903/frizh/) on 2020-11-13**:
Hi thank you for the refrence
I have figured it out with combination of your answer
regards

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2020-11-18**:
I'm glad it moved.